# Can we add more than 2 buttons to alert view UILocalnotification dialog

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

How can we add more than close and view button to UILocalNotification AlertView dialog.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the text of buttons but cannot add any new button according Apple Guide lines.